# dynamic object definition

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, declaration

This is a serious question, It has been nagging me for a while. In JavaScript you can declare a variable which has no type. It's type is often dynamic, depends on further value assigned to it.

e.g

```
var text;
typeof(text); //undefined

text = 'someText';
typeof(text); //string
```

So as we know that Javascript can dynamically change variable's type why these assignments are invalid then?

e.g

```
var someObj;
someObj.a = 'hello world';
console.log(someObj) //TypeError


var someTable;
someTable[0] = 'hello world';
console.log(someTable[0]) //TypeError
```

where this problem can be fixed just by adding definition to variable declaration:

```
var someObj = {};
var someTable = [];
```

I'd expect a good explanation of this problem. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Contrary to what you have said, the error does not occur when you log the variable because the code never reaches that point. Both variables are initialized to `undefined` which has no property `a` and no property `0`.

Comment: btw, `typeof` is an operartor, not a function.

Comment: The problem? Too funny. You can't add a property to `undefined`. Properties are assigned to `typeof varHere === 'object' && varHere !== null`. In layman's term Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Data types in Javascript are not dynamic, they are mutable. This means that depending on kind of operation you are applying to them they can change from being something into another thing (e.g. a number can become a string doing something like this: 4 + 'a').

2) The "error" is a consequence of having a variable not initialized. In Javascript when you are doing this:`var something = 'a'` 
you are doing two operations, a declaration, and an assignment. If you don't do the assignment and you try to access to a property of the object you have declared it will throw an error. In your case, you are declaring a variable but not initializing it to the "compiler" can't access the "a" property or the position 1 because it is of type `undefined`.

Comment: It is more a variable does not have a type, its value has a type.

Comment: Thank you. You explained where the problem lies in details and provided additional explanation which I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused about where the error is thrown. In your first example:

```
var someObj;
someObj.a = 'hello world'; // the error is thrown here
```

That error is thrown because `someObj` is `undefined` (**not** undeclared). So, you can't access the property `a` on `undefined`.

The same explanation applies for your second example:

```
var someTable;
someTable[0] = 'hello world'; // the error is thrown here
```

You're trying to access index `0` of `undefined`.

The reason that defining them as `{}` and `[]`, respectively, fixes your issue, is that you are then accessing property `a` of `{}` and index `0` of `[]`.

Comment: For the last point, *The reason that declaring them as {} and []*, it's actually **initialisation** and **not only a declaration**.

Answer (score 2):

There's a big difference between **declaration** and **initialisation** of variables.

When you declare a variable without initializing it with a `value`, its type will be `undefined`, **so when you will try to call it or access it**, it will give  `undefined`, because simply there were no `value` defined for the variable.

That's why it should be initialized:

```
var someObj = {};
var someTable = [];
```

So you can treat it as a `string`, an `object` or an `array` according its initialized `value`.

**Documentation:**

Please take a look at [**variables** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for further reading, where it says:

> A `var` statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and **are initialized to undefined when created**. [...] A variable defined by a VariableDeclaration with an **Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer’s AssignmentExpression** when the VariableDeclaration is executed, not when the variable is created.